# SIGSEGV error while uploading input

Tags: c++, algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

I tried to solve [the needle in the haystack problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NHAY/) in [ideone](http://ideone.com/iWAfx9), but I'm getting a SIGSEGV.

This is my code:

```
    //start
    #include<cstring>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include<vector> 
    using namespace std;


    int *overlap;
    char *pattern;
   //used Knuth morris prat algo
   void calcoverlap()
   {
    overlap[0] = 0;
    unsigned int length,i,len;  
    length=strlen(pattern);

    while(i<length)
    {
        if (pattern[i] == pattern[len])
        {
            len++;
            overlap[i] = len;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (len != 0)
            {
                len = overlap[len-1];
            }
            else
            {
                overlap[i++] = 0;
            }
        }

    }
   }
    //this is final function for pattern matching
    vector< int > patternmatching(int m)
{
vector< int > V;
int i = 0, j = 0;
char ch;
while(1)
{
ch = getchar();
if(ch == '\n') break;
while(1)
{
if(ch == pattern[j])
{
j++;
if(j == m)
{
V.push_back(i-m+1);
j = overlap[j];
}
break;
}
else if(j == 0) break;
else j = overlap[j];
}
i++;
}
    return V;
    }




   int main()
   {
        int n,i,sz;
        vector<int> V;
        while(scanf("%d",&n)==1)
        {   
            gets(pattern);
            calcoverlap();
            V=patternmatching(n);
            sz = V.size();
           for(i=0; i < sz; i++)
            printf("%d\n",V[i]);
            if(!sz) printf("\n");
            delete[] pattern;
            delete[] overlap;
        }
         return 0;
        }
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error only while uploading the input when normally this program runs fine and dandy.

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for pattern for a start.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Posting code and saying "please debug this for me" is not likely to get anyone to help you, since you've not demonstrated that you've made even a basic effort to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy to isolate a segfault (includes sigsegv) using a debugger.

If you are developing on Unix, please run your code in a debugger.

1. Compile your code with the `-g` flag.
2. Run your code in gdb as follows - `gdb a.out` (or name of program)
3. Run:  `(gdb) run`
4. Your program will crash at your segfault.  It should show you the exact line number it happens on.  You may have to type `bt` or `where` to trace it back.

In IDEs it's even easier.  Usually you debug by looking for a debug symbol, often graphically represented by a bug (e.g. Eclipse).  I'm not familiar with the IDE you use so perhaps if you have trouble someone could post an answer specific to that IDE.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179772/183887 for why this answer is appropriate

Comment: no issues but I am a simple coder ,I have never used unix, and I have used Ideone's compiler so my query still remains

Comment: @user2371549 your query will remain until you learn to use a debugger of your choice.  If you manage to solve this problem otherwise, you will have a similar query again in the very near future and get stuck again.  Better to learn to make life easy on yourself sooner than later.

Answer (score 2):

As Dav suggested in the comment, you use an uninitialized pointer (pattern) with gets, thus the segfault.